# Custome module is not showing to users XML,CSV access rights issue

Tags: python, odoo, openerp-7

Hello Openerp Developers. I have created a custom module today, It's working fine when accessing by **Admin**, But module menu is not appear on top menu bar when access by other users. I created the access rights in security folder, I think I done some thing wrong in **security.xml** or **csv files**, can somebody help me get out of this problem.

I listed my module files and code below. Check it Let me What I did wrong or What I missed out.

```
forum_view.xml,
forum.py, 
__init__.py,
__openerp__.py
security/forum_nyros_security.xml
security/ir.model.access.csv
```

**_*init*_.py**

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import forum
```

**_*openerp*_.py**

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

{
   'name' : "Nyros Discussion Forum",
   'category' : "Test",
   'version' : "1.0",
   'depends' : ['base','mail'],
   'author' : "Me",
   'description' : """\
     Open Academy modsule for managing trainings:
      - training courses
       - training sessions
     - attendees registration""",
   'data' : ['forum_view.xml',
             'security/forum_nyros_security.xml',
             'security/ir.model.access.csv'

             ],
}
```

**forum.py**

```
import datetime
import time
import openerp
from openerp.osv import osv, fields


class Course(osv.osv):
    _name = "forum.course"
    _inherit = ['mail.thread', 'ir.needaction_mixin']

    _columns = {
              'name' : fields.char(string="Question Title", size=256, required=True),
              'description' : fields.text(string="Question Description", required=True),
              'date_of_q_created': fields.datetime('Date of Created'),
              'category_question': fields.many2one('forum.categ', 'Question Category'),
              'create_uid': fields.many2one('res.users', 'Question Created By', readonly=True),
                 }

Course()
class question_categ(osv.osv):
    _name='forum.categ'
    _description='category of Question'
    _columns={
       'name':fields.char('Create a Category type',size=100)
    }
question_categ()
```

**forum_view.xml**

```
<openerp>
    <data>

        <!--  search view -->

        <record id="forum_search" model="ir.ui.view">
            <field name="name">forum.search</field>
            <field name="model">forum.course</field>
            <field name="type">search</field>
            <field name="arch" type="xml">
                <search string="Question Answer Discussion Forum">
                       <field name="name"/>
                       <field name="description"/>
                       <field name="date_of_q_created"/>
                </search>
            </field>
        </record>

        <!--  Tree View -->

        <record model="ir.ui.view" id="course_tree_view">
            <field name="name">forum.course.tree</field>
            <field name="model">forum.course</field>
            <field name="arch" type="xml">
                <tree string="Questions">
                    <field name="name"/>
                   <!-- <field name="description"/>-->
                    <field name="date_of_q_created" />
                    <field name="category_question"/>
                    <field name="create_uid"/>
                </tree>
            </field>
        </record>

        <!--  Form View -->

        <record model="ir.ui.view" id="course_form_view">
            <field name="name">forum.course.form</field>
            <field name="model">forum.course</field>
            <field name="type">form</field>
            <field name="arch" type="xml">
                <form string="Question and Answer" version = "v7">
                    <sheet>
                    <group string="Question">
                    <field name="name"/>
                    <field name="description"/>
                    <field name="date_of_q_created" />
                    <field name="category_question"/>
                    <field name="create_uid"/>
                    </group>
                    <group string="Answers and Comments">
                    <div class="oe_chatter">
                        <field name="message_follower_ids" widget="mail_followers" groups="base.group_user"/>
                        <field name="message_ids" widget="mail_thread"/>
                    </div>
                    </group>
                    </sheet>
                </form>
            </field>
        </record>

        <!--  Action View -->


    <record model="ir.actions.act_window" id="course_list_action">
        <field name="name">Questions form</field>
        <field name="res_model">forum.course</field>
                <field name="target">current</field>
        <field name="view_type">form</field>
        <field name="view_mode">tree,form</field>
    </record>

        <!-- Menu Items -->

        <menuitem id="main_forum_menu" name="Manage forum" />
        <menuitem id="forum_menu" name="Discussion Forum" parent="main_forum_menu" />
        <menuitem id="courses_menu" name="Questions sidemenu" parent="forum_menu" action="course_list_action" />


    </data>
</openerp>
```

**security/forum_nyros_security.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<openerp>
<data noupdate="1">
    <record id="group_forum_manager" model="res.groups">
        <field name="name">Forum Management/ Manager</field>
    </record>
    <record id="group_forum_user" model="res.groups">
        <field name="name">Forum Management / User</field>
    </record>
</data>
</openerp>
```

**security/ir.model.access.csv**

```
id,name,model_id:id,group_id:id,perm_read,perm_write,perm_create,perm_unlink
access_forum_course,forum.course,model_forum_course,forum_nyros.group_forum_user,1,1,1,1
access_forum_categ,forum.categ,model_forum_categ,forum_nyros.group_forum_user,1,1,1,1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try below line in your **_*openerp*_**.py file

```
'installable': True,
'auto_install': False,
```

Your **security/forum_nyros_security.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<openerp>
<data noupdate="0">
    <record model="ir.module.category" id="module_category_forum">
        <field name="name">Forum Management</field>
        <field name="sequence">7</field>
    </record>

    <record id="group_forum_user" model="res.groups">
        <field name="name">User</field>
        <field name="category_id" ref="module_category_forum"/>
        <field name="implied_ids" eval="[(4, ref('base.group_user'))]"/>
    </record>

    <record id="group_forum_manager" model="res.groups">
        <field name="name">Manager</field>
        <field name="category_id" ref="module_category_forum"/>
        <field name="implied_ids" eval="[(4, ref('group_forum_user'))]"/>
        <field name="users" eval="[(4, ref('base.user_root'))]"/>
    </record>
</data>
</openerp>
```

And your **security/ir.model.access.csv**

```
id,name,model_id:id,group_id:id,perm_read,perm_write,perm_create,perm_unlink
access_forum_course,forum.course,model_forum_course,group_forum_user,1,1,1,1
access_forum_categ,forum.categ,model_forum_categ,group_forum_user,1,1,1,1
```

Now do following steps.

- **Setting => Users => Click on Demo User**
- Now move to Access Rights => you will see **Forum Management**
- Select User and save it.
- Now Login with demo user you will see your Module.

**NOTE:** As Admin, You can give rights to the User. If the User don't have any access right to the  **Forum Management** (remain empty) than User will not show Module.

After this will you can show your module.

Comment: I tried what you said, But no change.
can you help me further..?

Comment: Sorry to say.. no change..  thanks for you help.. but can you help further in this.. still its not showing in users. I updated module, restarted server , No use.  can you find where went wrong

Comment: I don't know how you tested because as my end it's work. I added my answer and do each step.

Comment: Please tried this, and let me know any further problem.

Answer (score 0):

The code seems pretty ok to me.

What about your non-admin user. Is it in the new group? If not, please put it in there :-)

Comment: Groups were created, after adding the users to that group, module is accessible by users, but I want remove this "adding users to group " step, Can you tell me how can we allow both admin and users to have full access to module.

Comment: in your csv file substitute **base.group_user** for **group_forum_user** so every user got all rights for your new models

Answer (score 0):

In your openerp client,go to Settings/technical/Security/ access rights. Check whether your access created access right is there or not.